# "came round the corner" / "came out of the corner"

Tags: prepositions

> A car **came round the corner** at high speed.
>
> A car **came out of the corner** at high speed.

If I understand right, the difference between two sentences is in the direction of the car. In the first sentence the car is moving away, but in the second sentence the car is moving towards them. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't right.

*Coming* always implies movement towards the speaker. If a car *comes round the corner*, it appears from round a bend in the road.

*In the corner* refers to one of the angles of a room or other enclosure, so you are unlikely to see a car *coming out of a corner.*